# Ubuntu dual boot installation does not have install alongside and says unusable (cannot access windows 10 now)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have tried installing ubuntu with Windows 10 , but I don't get the message Install alongside windows 10 and when I press something else , the free space I have made is said to be unusable.  I have seen other similar questions , but all of them require to go back to windows and change things, but I cannot access windows 10 now , after I restart my pc it only loads Ubuntu installation

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90284/discussion-on-question-by-maverick98-ubuntu-dual-boot-installation-does-not-have).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild the BCD or scan the system.

1. Put the installation media in.
2. Open "Advanced Options" and then "Command Prompt".
3. Then, type in `sfc /scannow` or `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.

If something's gone wrong, feel free to comment under this post!

EDIT: Didn't see your question. I don't think if this will help you, but you can try.

Comment: Was thinking more about  `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`  instead. Must go now. We are borderline with added comments @Maverick98.

Comment: @Mikemecanic Well, that would work too. He can type 2 of them. Nothing bad will happen if he types 3 commands anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing C: drive to create a dedicated partition did not work. Boot screenshot shows no bootloader, it was deleted accidentally. Before trying something else, launch the Ubuntu installer and recover important files.

You'll find them under user in the Windows drive. Copy them on a second flash drive. Please post a screenshot of Disk or Gparted.